# How can I perform two different functions on a collection based on grouping with a stream?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to refactor some not so elegant code using a stream. I have a HashMap containing Strings and MyObjects and currently iterating over it using a for loop like so:

```
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, MyObject> objectsToAdd = new HashMap<>();


for(MyObject object : map.values()){
        String idToAdd = object.getConnectedToId();

        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(idToAdd) {
            continue;
        }

        if(idToAdd.substring(0,1).equals("i")){ // connected to an ICS
            MyObject newObject = service1.someMethod(idToAdd);

            if(newObject != null) {
                objectsToAdd.put(newObject.getId(), newObject);
            }
        } else if (idToAdd.substring(0,1).equals("d")){ // connected to a device
            MyObject newObject = service2.someMethod(idToAdd);
            if(newObject != null) {
                objectsToAdd.put(newObject.getId(), newObject);
            }
        }

    }

    map.putAll(objectsToAdd);
```

Since I only care about the ids, I started by using the map operation to get only the ids, followed by a filter operation to eliminate an empty ones.

The next part is what I am having trouble with. The first thing I tried was using the Collectors groupingBy operation so that I could group the items based on the first character of the id and I ended up with this:

```
        map.values().stream()
            .map(myObject -> myObject.getConnectedToId()) // get a map of all the ids
            .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty) // filter non empty ones
            .collect(
                Collectors.mapping(
                    MyObject::getId,
                    Collectors.toList())),
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                            s -> s.substring(0,1));
```

This link helped with the reduction using Stream collectors: [Stream Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)

We have at least two problems with this code: 1) collect is a [terminal operation](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/stream-terminal-operations-example/) which will close the stream and we haven't finished yet and 2) We still need the original object but it has now been reduced to a map of connectedToIds.

Q1) Is there an intermediate operation that will allow us to group the objects based on the first character of the id?

Q2) How can we do this without reducing the collection to only the ids?

Q3) And lastly, once the collection has been grouped (there will be two), how can we perform separate functions on each group as in the original code?

---

Final Solution (thanks to @Holger & @Flown for the help)

```
    Map<Character, Function<String, MyObejct>> methodMapping = new HashMap<>();
    methodMapping.put('i', service1::method1);
    methodMapping.put('d', service2::method2);

    Map<String, MyObject> toAdd = map.values().stream().map(MyObject::getConnectedToId)
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
        .map(id -> methodMapping.getOrDefault(id.charAt(0), i -> null).apply(id))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getId, Function.identity(), (mo1, mo2) -> mo2));

    map.putAll(toAdd);
```

To avoid a concurrent modification exception, it is necessary to first store the objects in a temporary map while performing the stream operations and then once finished, add them to the final map.

Comment: I assume that the key of the map is the `id` of `MyObject`? I.e. `map.get(object.getId()).equals(object) == true`

Comment: Yes, the key in the HashMap is the id of MyObject. I made a minor edit to the question for clarity - the idToAdd is the connectedToId on the myObject, rather than the object's id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Stream` approach and your common approach are very different in terms of return types. Therefore I transformed your former approach to the `Stream` API.

To reduce some of your code you should first build a `Map<Character, Function<String, MyObject>>` to do a concise lookup in a mapping step.
Looks something like this:

```
Map<Character, Function<String, MyObject>> serviceMapping = new HashMap<>();
serviceMapping.put('i', service1);
serviceMapping.put('d', service2);
```

How does the pipeline work?

1. map `MyObject` -> `MyObject::getConnectedToId`
2. filter empty `Strings`
3. perform a lookup in the `serviceMap`. If it is present, then return the `Function<String, MyObject>`, else `id -> null`
4. filter `null` values
5. last step is to collect the result by providing the right extractor functions

---

```
Map<String, MyObject> toAdd = map.values().stream().map(MyObject::getConnectedToId)
    .filter(StringUtils::isEmpty)
    .map(id -> serviceMapping.getOrDefault(id.charAt(0), i -> null).apply(id))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyObject::getId, Function.identity(), (mo1, mo2) -> mo2));
map.putAll(toAdd);
```

---

It is also possible to add the computed values directly to `map` by using `forEach` operation.

```
map.values().stream().map(MyObject::getConnectedToId)
    .filter(StringUtils::isEmpty)
    .map(id -> serviceMapping.getOrDefault(id.charAt(0), i -> null).apply(id))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEach(mo -> map.put(mo.getId(), mo));
```

Comment: Are mo1 and mo2 assumed to be method1 and method2?

Also, in the last collect operation I am getting "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @Kristina If there is a collision of already existing values then the default `Collectors::toMap` would throw an exception. Therefore you've to provide a merging function which is responsible for deciding which element is taken, the new or old value (`(mo1, mo2) -> mo2`).

Comment: @Holger Everything up until the `map` operation is working. I had to make one modification to the `serviceMapping` because it wants the function that is returning the `MyObject`. 
            `Map<Character, Function<String, DeviceMapObject>> methodMapping = new HashMap<>();
        methodMapping.put('i', service1::getMOById);
        methodMapping.put('d', service2::getMOById);`
Does this look right? The methods do not seem to be called in this case and instead the `map` operation is returning no results

Comment: @Kristina: you didn’t tell us anything about `service1` and `service2`. If they implement the same interface or have a common base class defining the `getMOById` method, the solution could be simplified.

Comment: @Holger: unfortunately, they do not implement the same interface or have a common base class. Each service returns two different DTO objects, which are then wrapped with a `MyObject` before being returned.

Comment: @Holger after some debugging, I have it working now. Thanks for the help! Final solution is posted on the original question